# Can length recognize a condition?

Tags: r

I was wondering why my `length()` command in the below R code is always giving 1? I want to know the number of `p`s that are smaller or equal to `.05` out of `n` `p`s?

```
n = 1e3
p = runif(n, 0, 1)
length(p <= .05)/n # why just gives 1, while it should be less than 1.
```

Comment: Did you meant `mean(p <= .05)`

Comment: @akrun, does `mean(p <= .05)` give the number of `p`s that are smaller or equal to `.05` out of `n`?

Comment: Yes, yes `mean(p <= .05)` does exactly that. You could also use `sum(p <= .05)/n`. Way less efficiently, but closer to your attempt, would be `length(which(p <= .05))/n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
n = 1e3
p = runif(n, 0, 1)
length(which(p <= .05))/n
```

Just using `length` will give you the length of the boolean vector obtained which also includes the `FALSE` cases too. The `which` function will filter out only the `TRUE` cases and then you can measure the `length` of only the `TRUE` cases.

Comment: thanks, it seems `mean(p <= .05)` does the same thing.

Comment: @rnorouzian Yes there are multiple ways to do a lot of things in R.

Answer (score 4):

In R, operators (e.g., <, >, =) return a logical vector indicating which element(s) fulfill the specific condition. `p <= .05` outputs a vector or `TRUE` and `FALSE` for each element, depending on whether it is <= to .05 (`TRUE`) or not (`FALSE`). If you want to count the number of `TRUE` elements in the vector you can do so as follows: **Method 1:** In R, `TRUE` has a value of 1 and `FALSE` a value of 0. Therefore, to count the number of `TRUE` elements in a logical vector, you can just take the sum of it (e.g., `sum(p <= .05`). **Method 2:** You can take an actual subset of your vector `p` to view the elements which are <= .05. One way to do so is with `p[p <= .05]`, where the square brackets after `p` mean "from p, take all p that is less than or equal to .05." You can take the length of this vector (`length(p[p <= .05]`) if all you want is how many elements in `p` are <= .05.